# Using async/await with respondWith

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, service-worker

I have two bits of code which i would expect to have worked in the same way however they dont - only one actually works and i cant figure out why.

Working one

```
    self.addEventListener('fetch',(e)=>{
    
       e.respondWith(handleRequest(e.request))
    
    })
    
    async function handleRequest(req){
      const res = await fetch(req);
      const cache = await caches.open(cacheName)
    
      if(res.ok){
        // add the response to the caches and return the response
        await cache.put(req, res.clone())
        return res;
    
      }else{
        const res = cache.match(req)
        return res
      }
    }
```

non working one

```
    self.addEventListener('fetch',(e)=>{
    
      
       e.respondWith(async () => {
    
        const res = await fetch(e.request);
        const cache = await caches.open(cacheName)
    
        if(res.ok){
          // add the response to the caches and return the response
          await cache.put(e.request, res.clone())
          return res;
        }else{
          const res = cache.match(e.request)
          return res
        }
       })
    
    })
```

Can anyone see why this is?

Comment: in your `async arrow function pass `e.request` as a parameter as you did for normal function call.

Comment: But isnt it already in scope?

Comment: In the first example, you're passing the result of a function call. In the second, you're creating a functions and then passing a reference to it, but not actually calling it.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Ouruborus you only passing the function reference instead of the function result. Compare this two example

```
console.log(() => { return 'test' });
```

vs.

```
console.log((() => { return 'test' })());
```

If you rewrite your code like this it should work:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {
    e.respondWith((async () => {
        const res = await fetch(e.request);
        const cache = await caches.open(cacheName)

        if (res.ok) {
            // add the response to the caches and return the response
            await cache.put(e.request, res.clone())
            return res;
        } else {
            const res = cache.match(e.request)
            return res
        }
    })());
});
```